# Mizrachim saying Avinu Malkeinu on Shabbat

Tags: minhag, shabbat, high-holidays

I would like to turn around [these](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4380/15256) [two](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10577/15256) questions. We saw that it is problematic to ask personal requests on Shabbat, and certain verses of *Avinu Malkeinu* correspond to the blessings of the weekday *Amidah*. However, our *Mizrachi* brothers do say it on Shabbat. What is their reasoning, what sources do they have?

Answer (score 3):

The [Ra'van on Yuma](https://sites.google.com/site/sagesofashkenaz/Home/seforim-index/title-search-2/raavan/ravaan-yoma) writes:
( ראב"ן יומא ד״ה
ובמוצאי של יוה"כ )

> וגם אומרים אבינו מלכינו לערב שבת ושבת שבין ר"ה ליוהכ"פ
>   And we say Avinu Malkeinu on Friday and on Shabbos between Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur

(Indeed while the Rama (OC 602) sounds like Avinu Malkeinu is said on Friday afternoon before Shabbos Shuva, the Yad Ephraim in 554 says the custom in his locale was not to. In any event it seems some Eidos Mizrach communities do say it even on Shabbos Shuva itself.)

I haven't seen a reason for allowing this. Perhaps the reasoning of the Baal HaTanya can be applied here, since Shabbos Shuva is an Eis Ratzon, and if not when?

In the Eidus Mizrachi Siddur I have with the Haskama of HaRav HaGaon Ovadia Yosef ztz"l they mention saying Avinu Malkeinu on Shabbos Shuva, they omit three of the lines (they're written smaller).

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Edot_HaMizrach%2C_Shabbat_Shacharit%2C_Amidah.51?lang=bi

Comment: Which page in Yoma has those words?

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the discussion of Friday afternoon. Moreover, isn't ראב"ן from Ashkenaz?

Comment: In most Ashkenazi communities Avinu Malkeinu is not said on Friday Afternoon.  So we see a precedent that Ashkenazi Communities don't say it then, but some do, and we see therefore that this is probably down to minhag.  The Ravan is a Rishon.  What does it matter where he is from, he is a Rishon that supports this view.  In any case the Ravan was born in Provence ([according to Wikipedia][1]).  He then moved around the Ashkenazi centers, before settling in Toledo, Spain. [1]: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/אברהם_בן_נתן

Comment: One must remember that the minhagim of Sefardim vs. Ashkenazim were being developed during this time, and locations are not necessarily indicators of minhagim.  Whereas later on (by the 16th Century) they do become indicators.